# Rails 3.2.6 cache_sweeper not working for a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using fragment caching in a Rails 3.2.6 application running Ruby 1.8.7

In my controller I have:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   cache_sweeper :product_sweeper
```

The sweeper works for C-UD actions but not for my POST method "changeorder".

I tried:

```
  cache_sweeper :product_sweeper, :only =>
```

and added all the C-UD and also :changeorder but that didn't work.

I added this to my sweeper:

```
 def after_product_changeorder(product)
   expire_cache(product)
 end
```

and it doesn't error but it doesn't work either. I removed the product_ and that didn't error and it didn't work.

I did change it to _product**s** and that did error.

The only way I could expire the fragment was with a:

```
expire_fragment('page_home')
```

in the changeorder controller method.

For the record here is my sweeper:

```
class ProductSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  def after_save(product)
    expire_cache(product)
  end

  def after_destroy(product)
    expire_cache(product)
  end

  private

    def expire_cache(product)
      # expire_page products_path 
      # expire_page product_path(product)
      expire_fragment('page_home')
    end

end
```

and my controller method:

```
def changeorder
  params[:product].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Product.update_all(['displayorder=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

and my routes file - it might be helpful:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    post 'changeorder'
  end
end
```

I did change the 'changeorder' to PUT but that didn't make any difference either.

Any ideas here? I've been through a stack load of SO pages and not found anything that works, found loads of helpful stuff in other areas, so it isn't wasted time on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The clue was from the error I got and the fact that I will only be using fragment cacheing.

My sweeper now looks like this:

```
class ProductSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Product

  def after_save
    expire_cache
  end

  def after_destroy
    expire_cache
  end

  def after_products_changeorder
    expire_cache
  end

  private

    def expire_cache
      expire_fragment('page_home')
    end

end
```

No need to pass in a product as I don't have a show page.

It is going to be a little more complex for the pages where I do have a show page!!